# How can I download a Meteor application sent by MUP?

Tags: node.js, linux, meteor, mup

I have lost the Meteor application files that have been sent via MUP, which are on different Linux servers in Digital Ocean. Is there an easy way to download the developed applications so I can make the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Build application from docker

but javascript and all files are bundled & compresses you cannot modify them easily.

To retrieve deployed app. open server and use docker to get deployed app
its located inside /opt/:yourappname:/ in docker.